# Android TV - Error == Cant Open This Right Now

Tags: xamarin, android-intent, android-activity, android-tv, android-launcher

I have an android app that works just fine on the Phone. When I deploy to a tv it loads. But when I leave the app and come back to it (MultiTask) I get an error. = Cant Open This Right Now.
No matter what emulator I use, delete bin, obj, clean and so on. The error does not go away.
[image]

I have tried adding different combinations such as launcher, main. Delete one or the other and still nothing works. When I deploy to the phone it works fine.

Activity that I use is called MainActivity and the MainLauncher is set to true.

Is there a setting im missing that would allow multitask in android?

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:exported="false" android:label="App Name">
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

Tried all combinations.

Comment: Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in MAUI and for me helped to change android:exported to explicit true